# Realm.io build errors when using cocoapods `use_frameworks!`

Tags: ios, cocoapods, realm

**Goal:** Be able to use swift pods in an ObjC project

**Steps Taken:**

- Altered `Podfile` by appending `use_frameworks!`
- Ran `pod install` (Cocoapods version 1.0.0)
- Built workspace again

**Result (Errors):**

- I get the following [Realm.io](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) errors (pod installed from `pod 'Realm'` since I'm coding in ObjC):

  - `RLMRealm.h:51:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'RLMRealm'`
  - `RLMRealm.h:95:62: Property has a previous declaration`
  - `RLMRealm.h:105:38: Property has a previous declaration`
  - `RLMRealm.h:110:56: Property has a previous declaration`
  - `RLMRealm.h:115:38: Property has a previous declaration`
  - `RLMRealm.h:297:28: Property has a previous declaration`
  - `RLMRealm.h:493:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'RLMNotificationToken'`

**Problem-Solving Steps Taken:**

- (Previous ones in edit history that led to this simplified question)
- Deleted all pods and reinstalled (no effect)
- Unlinked Pods framework in Build Phases and relinked (no effect)
- Cleaned and built / Cleaned build folder and built (no effect)
- Tried importing with `""`, `<>`, and `@import` (currently all imports in my code are done with `#import <Realm/Realm.h>`) (searched with `#import <Realm` and `#import "Realm`) (no effect)
- Created new project, copied files over, and pod installed (no effect)
- Searched project folder for `"@interface RLMNotificationToken"` and only found one instance of the `RLMRealm.h` file, so I don't have duplicates
- **Deleting all of my files except for `AppDelegate.h/m` builds successfully**
- **Searched for `#import "R`, `#import <R`, `@import R` and found a rogue `#import <RLMRealm.h>`**

**Questions:**

I'm frankly really confused and not sure what to do at this point.

***So how do I fix these build errors? Why is this happening? Or what other problem-solving steps should I try?*** (Answers to any of these questions would be appreciated)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build folder (not to be confused with just `clean`)? In Xcode, go to the Product menu while holding down the Alt/Option key and choose the "Clean Build Folder..." option; see if it helps.

Comment: @AustinZ - Good thought! Unfortunately that didn't work either. Anything else you would suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently one of my files had a `#import <RLMRealm.h>` in it (not sure how that got in there). I changed that to `@import Realm;` and it all works now. I missed that when searching before and only found it while combing my code. Interesting that it works with the library but not with the framework. Well, figured it out and it's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

Realm pod for swift is `"RealmSwift"`. I think you are using objective-c pod.

Have a look at this link [Realm for Swift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/). You can also drag and drop realm framework, this will save from errors you have been facing.

Comment: I'm writing code in Objective-C though... Isn't `'RealmSwift'` optimized for Swift and somewhat incompatible with ObjC (won't be able to use generic types, etc.)?

Comment: Both languages have different pods. You can't use them interchangeably. If your goal is to use swift then you will have to use  'RealmSwift'.

Comment: Oh, I can't use a swift pod with an objc project, even with `use_frameworks!`?

Comment: The swift pod isn't having problems though. Probably some Realm installation steps required for using mixed pods?

Answer (score 0):

Please check all places, where you import Realm classes. In my case I imported `#import <RLMArray.h>`. Should be `#import <Realm/RLMArray.h>`